# What is the subgroup generated by $\{(12),(23)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I tried to use the definition of generated set  as follow

The subgroup generated by $X$, $X$ subset of group $G$, is the intersection of all subgroups  which contain $X$.

My question: if $S_3$ is symmetric group, what is the subgroup generated by $\{(12),(23)\}$?

I tried and I found the $S_3$ is the only group satisfies the definition.

Comment: it is wrong, S_3 generated by two elements one of them have order 3.

Comment: @MeMe You can generate $S_3$ also by order $2$ elements.

Comment: So even $\{(13),(23)\}$ also generate $S_3$?

Comment: Yes, they give me $(123)$ and $(132)$, respectively.

Comment: You can also argue as follows if you prefer to avoid explicitly calculating products. Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $(12)$, and let $K$ be the subgroup generated by $(23)$. Clearly $|H| = |K| = 2$, and $|H \cap K| = 1$. Then $|HK| = |H||K|/|H \cap K| = 4$. Since the subgroup generated by $H$ and $K$ must contain $HK$, its size must be at least $4$. But the only integer $\geq 4$ which divides $6$ is $6$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

$S_3$ is generated by all of its two cycles. These are $(12) $, $(13)$, and $(23)$. But $(23)^{-1} (12) (23) = (13) $, so $(13)$ is in the subgroup generated by $\{(12), (23)\} $, and so the subgroup generated is all of $S_3$.